# Extra pixels in CSS radiobutton group buttons that won't go away

Tags: javascript, css

EDIT: Changed the post name, which was incorrectly titled from another post !!

I have been building a sports app in React over the last several months, and I am struggling with a small cosmetic issue with my radio buttons. Immensely frustrating is the fact that despite my attempt at a reproducible example, the bug does not appear in my example below, although fortunately a variant of the issue is occurring. Here are my buttons:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      oneTwoFour: "1 Graph",
      quarter: "All"
    }
  } 
    
  handleQuarterChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ quarter: event.target.value });
  };
  handleOneTwoFourChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ oneTwoFour: event.target.value });
  }; 
    
  render() {
    
    const { oneTwoFour, quarter } = this.state;
  
    const oneTwoFourOptions = ["1 Graph", "2 Graphs", "4 Graphs"];
    const oneTwoFourButtons =
      <form>
          <div className="blg-buttons">
              {oneTwoFourOptions.map((d, i) => {
                  return (
                      <label key={'onetwofour-' + i}>
                          <input
                              type={"radio"}
                              value={oneTwoFourOptions[i]}
                              checked={oneTwoFour === oneTwoFourOptions[i]}
                              onChange={this.handleOneTwoFourChange}
                          />
                          <span>{oneTwoFourOptions[i]}</span>
                      </label>
                  )
              })}
          </div>
       </form>; 

    const quarterOptions = ["All", "OT", "Half 1", "Half 2", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"];
    const quarterButtons = 
      <form>
          <div className="blg-buttons">
              {quarterOptions.map((d, i) => {
                  return (
                      <label key={'quarter-' + i} style={{"width":"50%"}}>
                          <input
                              type={"radio"}
                              value={quarterOptions[i]}
                              checked={quarter === quarterOptions[i]}
                              onChange={this.handleQuarterChange}
                          />
                          <span>{quarterOptions[i]}</span>
                      </label>
                  )
              })}
          </div>
      </form>; 
  
    return(
      <div>
        <div style={{"width":"25%", "float":"left", "margin":"0 auto", "padding":"5px"}}>
          {quarterButtons}
        </div>

        <div style={{"width":"25%", "float":"left", "margin":"0 auto", "padding":"5px"}}>
            {oneTwoFourButtons}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.blg-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=radio] {
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=radio] + span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1;

    font-size: 1.0vw;
    padding: 0.5vw;
    border-radius: 0.35vw;
    border: 0.15vw solid #333;

    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    background: #EEE;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + span {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + span:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #888;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:checked + span{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #EEE;
}

.blg-buttons label {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: calc(0.85vw);
    margin-bottom: 0.1vw;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

Also, here is a screenshot of an inspection of the buttons in my app (can be found at bigleaguegraphs.com/nba/shotcharts-pro as well), showing the true error that I am having:

[image]
The error is in this overhang of the buttons that **is not due to padding or margin**. I have seemingly gone through every single aspect of the CSS styling my radio buttons, and I have no idea why the element extends a few extra pixels outward to the right.

Amazingly / unfortunately, this is not occurring in the example above, although there is a **different issue** in the example above where the label element extends a few extra pixels upward (instead of rightward), that I cannot account for.

Any help with removing this extra couple of pixels on the button group would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.blg-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap;  you shouldn't need this */
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

 .blg-buttons label {
    display: flex;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0.85vw;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px; /* you don't need that 0.1vw */
    font-weight: 700;
 }

.blg-buttons input[type=radio]+span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: .5vw;
    border-radius: .35vw;
    border: .15vw solid #333;
    width: 90%;
    /* text-align: center; <-- you don't need this with flex */
    color: #333;
    background: #eee;
}
```

You should try and use flexbox where possible. I worked this out by playing with your site, so where i saw `.nba_scp_cp_rbs` i replaced with `.blg-buttons` (hope that's right). But yeh, avoid using stuff like `width: 90%`, with flex you rarely have to explicitly define widths, and you can size things based on padding & margins, leading to way less weird sizing bugs like yours :)

[picture proof of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW9Pn.png)

Comment: i had a feeling the `width = 90%` stuff was bad, but wasnt sure

Comment: "You should try and use flexbox where possible" - you should rather use it whenever it offers you the best options for the layout you want to create. The `grid` layout for example is a perfect example of a viable alternative

Comment: i guess my wording is a bit misleading - i meant in the context of this code (and the html i saw on the site). I agree grid can be a good option (although i personally still favour flex)

Comment: yes thank you, i struggle with laying out widgets on a page but agree that flexbox is pretty good in this regard.

Comment: i am attempting to turn the radio buttons into two columns currently and will post a follow up if i cannot achieve this